# Is an IntentService suitable for Geofences

Tags: android, android-geofence, android-intentservice

I am using the Android Developers sample app for geofencing as a basic for my own geofencing app.

I have the impression that the geofences don't get trough a while after the application is killed.
I noticed that this sample app uses an IntentService instead of a Service.

Should I convert the IntentService to a regular Service to be able to keep getting these geofencing intents?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the application is killed'. Swiped away from the recents, crashed, left last activity or pressed force stop on app info?

Comment: Swiped away from the recents.

Comment: By swiping from recent you are stopping the app and its normal to stop getting intents. Should be the same with service

Comment: Regular Services can get restarted by the system even if swiped away. Also I doubt that PendingIntents of an app are removed if swiped away. That would make a lot of apps useless. Which Android version are you running on?

Comment: I am running Marshmallow.

Comment: But it does work for a while (even after swiped away) yes? If so then maybe the service is crashing. After 3 crashes the system wont bother to start the crashing service again unless the user restarts the app.